# Use PHP to hold HTML while keeping animation

Tags: php, html

Good Evening,
I have a website and so far I am copying the navigation code across every page. Annoying right  :)

However I'd like to use PHP or something to hold the HTML so I only have to edit one file. However because of the way the navigation bar operates there's a class called  which keeps the clicked link highlighted to show the user which page they are on.

Here's the code:

```
<nav>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><strong><strong>Home</strong></strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html"><strong><strong>services</strong></strong></a>
                          <ul>
                                <li><a herf="services.html">Repairs</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="phonerep.html">Phone Repairs</a>
                                      <li><a href="podrep.html">Ipod Repairs</a>
                                    <li><a href="padrep.html">Ipad Repairs</a>
                                  <li><a href="comprep.html">Computer & Laptop Repairs</a>
                                  </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="compmain.html">Maintenance & Upgrades</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="compmain.html">Computers & Laptops</a>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="tuition.html">Tutoring</a></li>
                              <li><a href="spechelp.html">Specialist Help</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="iphone.html"><strong><strong>Prices</strong></strong></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="iphone.html">Iphone</a>
                                 <li><a href="ipod.html">Ipod</a>
                                  <li><a href="ipad.html">Ipad</a>
                                    <li><a href="complap.html">Computer and Laptop</a>
                          </ul>
                        <li><a href="about.html"><strong><strong>about</strong></strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html"><strong><strong>Contact</strong></strong></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Dump it inside a `.php` file and then use `include()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is an *extremely* common thing to do, one you don't necessarily even need to happen on the server. I suggest either using a publishing system like WordPress or Drupal, or looking at some of the menu systems out there. Also, look at templates; I like http://twig.sensiolabs.org/, but there's a whole lot like Smarty, Flexy, vanilla PHP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do it for you, but what you could do that is very simple is to do something like this (of course there are more elegant methods, but let's stick to the K.I.S.S. principle here since it seems like you are new to PHP):

**myMenu.php**

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li <?PHP if($PAGE == 'home') echo 'class="active">'; ?>><a href="index.html"><strong><strong>Home</strong></strong></a></li>
    <li <?PHP if($PAGE == 'service') echo 'class="active">'; ?>><a href="services.html"><strong><strong>services</strong></strong></a>
    <ul>
      <li <?PHP if($PAGE == 'home') echo 'class="active">'; ?>><a herf="services.html">Repairs</a> <--Type here, should be href, not herf! :-)
[...]
```

All you'd have to do is define the `$PAGE` variable before you call your include on each page with the appropriate string.

**index.php:**

```
$PAGE = 'home';
include 'myMenu.php';
```

**services.php:**

```
$PAGE = 'services';
include 'myMenu.php';
```

---

You could also use Javascript, but since you posted this in the PHP/HTML tags, I'm going to leave you alone for now!

Comment: I got to thinking about it, and one of the frameworks I had looked at recently for a REST connector was [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/). The whole point and purpose is to keep it small and direct, perfect for a RESTful interface... and really simple HTML flat-file only sites like the one the OP has. So I did a quick search and found [this blog entry](http://blog.joalahdesigns.com/2012/05/09/a-slim-php-framework/). Do you think this could be adapted in such a way that users like the OP could easily understand how to implement? It seems dead-simple to me, but that may not be the case.

Comment: It does seem really light and simple! But I can't really speak for OP... I've seen a lot of people in web-related tags (especially in the php tag) that don't really consider themselves programmers, but more like designers (and to them, web is just another medium). Some of them are also just working on their own small business' website. If that's the case with OP, he probably wants to keep everything code-related to a minimum (while saving himself trouble when he edits the menu). That is just the feeling I get from reading the question, but I could be dead wrong.

Comment: I didn't even answer your question (my bad)...
I think OP could probably use it (with the blog entry) and if it works the first time, then everything's good. I'm more worried about if it doesn't work (server configuration, framework configuration, etc...), then he might get frustrated pretty fast if he has no idea of what it is and how it works. TBH, I can't really answer...

Comment: Yes, it is hard to gauge other's level of awareness and general knowledge on this site. I've been there, where I knew it wasn't working but it felt harder to change than to fix and patch what's already there. That's why it's always better to start with a tool than to build one, as long as it's competent. I might roll something together real quick as a demonstration. One thing about Slim is that there's so little to it, it's hard to screw up. But, y'know, the creativity of inexperienced coders in rube goldberging a crying simple task continues to amaze me, although I can sympathize.